# Cannot open pycharm in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm

I have Python 2.7 and pycharm version is 4.0.6 on Ubuntu. When I tried to open it via terminal I got the following error : "**ERROR: Cannot start PyCharm
Required tools are missing - check beginning of "./pycharm.sh" file for details.**
". Any Suggestions?

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but: Did you check the beginning of `pycharm.sh`?

Comment: Yes. But cannot find anything.

Comment: Have you got either of the two recommended JREs? Oracle JRE 1.6+ or OpenJDK 1.7+ (See: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/system_requirements.jsp?os=linux).

Comment: Looking at the recent `pycharm.sh`, that error message indicate that one of `uname`, `egrep`, `cut`, `mktemp`, `rm`, `cat` and `tr` can't be found. That's rare for Ubuntu.

Comment: Please check if you can run all there command in the Terminal!

Comment: Yes. I have oracle java 1.7 . JAVA_HOME is also there.

Comment: Cool..... tr was missing. I installed coreutils and it solved the issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: Same problem here. What I could do to at least open Pycharm is to `cd ......bin`(as Pycharm suggest), then `./pycharm.sh` to open it. That's weird.